# Wordpress wp_insert_post() returns 0 but not not wp_error

Tags: code

`wp_insert_post()` return value says:

> (int|WP_Error) The post ID on success. The value 0 or WP_Error on
> failure.

Okay, I' have an import routine running and all but a few (about 20) of them import correctly.  The ones that fail have a return value of 0 but `is_wp_error()` is NOT true.   How do I find out what happened and why these certain articles won't import properly? At least if `is_wp_error()` was returned you could print out the message.

Thanks.

P.S. Here is the code that adds the article.  Note: I'm also not sure why AdminNotice::displayError doesn't do anything (that's why I added log output).  Am I supposed to put some type of tag on the page (it's my first ever plugin for a single task)? I got that bit of code from [How to add an admin notice upon post save/update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152033/how-to-add-an-admin-notice-upon-post-save-update)

```
       /**
        * Adds a knowledge base article and assign tags and category
        * @param $title The title of the article
        * @param $content The content of the article
        * @param $category The category of the article
        * @param $tags An array of tags to assign to the article
        */
        function add_ht_kb_article($title, $content, $category, $tags = array() )
        {

            $content=trim($content);
            if( !empty ( $content ) ){
                $new_article = array(
                      'post_content'   => wp_filter_post_kses($content),
                      'post_title'     => $title,
                      'post_status'    => 'publish',
                      'post_type'      => 'ht_kb'
                    );

                $new_article_id = wp_insert_post($new_article);

                if (is_wp_error($new_article_id)) {
                    $this->log("Failed (wp_error) to add article {$title}");
                    $this->log($new_article_id->get_error_message());
                    //return false;
                }
                else if( $new_article_id != 0 ){
                    //ht_kb_categories
                    $res=wp_set_object_terms( $new_article_id, intval($category), 'ht_kb_category', true );
                    if (is_wp_error($res)) {
                        $this->log("Failed to add category ID {$category}");
                        AdminNotice::displayError("Failed to add category ID {$category}");
                        return false;
                    }
                    

                    //ht_kb_tags
                    foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
                        $tag_slug = sanitize_title($tag);
                        $res=wp_set_object_terms( $new_article_id, $tag_slug, 'ht_kb_tag', true );
                        if (is_wp_error($res)) {
                            $this->log("Failed to add key tag {$tag_slug}");
                            AdminNotice::displayError("Failed to add key tag {$tag_slug}");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $this->log("Failed (zero) to add article {$title}");
                    AdminNotice::displayError("Failed to add article {$title}");
                    //return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can ask [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to return a `WP_Error` on failure by setting the 2nd parameter to `true` (it defaults to false).

So if you change

```
$new_article_id = wp_insert_post($new_article);
```

to

```
$new_article_id = wp_insert_post( $new_article, true );
```

in your code, you should get `WP_Error` objects back that you can then inspect.

Comment: Found reason and it's the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027256/wordpress-db-insert-error-when-using-insert-post